# Summer 17 cannot add Email to activity in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-experience, summer-17

I am testing the new Summer 17 release.

I have a sandbox org with this release and all my `Send Email` lightning action tabs in all the activity layouts are gone:

[image]

I am trying through the page layout (contact, opportunity and all) to add it - now there is an `Email` lightning action to add:

[image]

But after I am saving the page layout, I do not see this lightning action - it never shows the `Email` tab in the activity pane, and also it seems like it is not getting saved because when I get back to the page layout, the `Email` lightning action is again unselected.

I have tried this also on a new page layout and it behaves the same.

Am I missing something or this is a bug?

Thanks

Itai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check your orgs email deliverability: Setup -> Email -> Deliverability

it needs to be set to All Email, for the email action to be visible

cheers
ian

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks @ian church. question is - why did this got disabled with the new summer 17 release - it was enabled before that. Anyways thanks a lot.