# "New Email" button does not display in Lightning

Tags: lightning, email, global-actions

Even though "New Email" button has been added to the Lightning button bar on the Account page layout, the Button does not show up in Salesfoce Lightning page layout for the Account page layout. Is there a bug with this in Lightning?

[image]

Comment: It's a JavaScript button, isn't it?

Comment: as they say here in Ireland, I haven't a rashers! But I suspect its baked in rather than JavaScript, same as Log a call, New Task, New Event buttons. I'll attach screenshot to the question for clarity.

Comment: I have the same problem in my summer 17 sandbox - I have asked a question about it but got no answers: [Summer 17 cannot add Email to activity in lightning experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173334/summer-17-cannot-add-email-to-activity-in-lightning-experience). Any help would be great!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is your org set to All Email, for the email action to be visible :

Setup -> Email -> Deliverability

Comment: deliverability: Access level: All email, still no show

Answer (score 0):

1st of all need to check Email -> Deliverability is set uo to all emails.
2nd Thing - Please check on Layouts under Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions --- drag and drop email option to list of available actions. Try to swap and put email action on the front.